# Fetch MySQL table data with specific value

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to edit the value and/or add more values to table *options* using PHP, here is a screen shot:

---

[image: table name is]

---

I started of with the following, now Im trying to see how I can pull the  data that's associated with form_field_id, in this example is 5.

```
<?php

require_once("config/database.php");

$con = mysql_connect($config["db_server"],$config["db_user"],$config["db_pass"]);
mysql_select_db($config['db_name'], $con);

// get value of id that sent from address bar
$id=$_GET['form_field_id'];

// Retrieve data from database
$sql="SELECT * FROM options WHERE id='$form_field_id'";    


$result=mysql_query($sql);
$rows=mysql_fetch_array($result);

?>  


<form name="form1" method="post" action="updated_values.php">

<input name="name" class="form-control" type="text" id="name" value="<? echo $rows['value']; ?>">
<input name="name" class="form-control" type="text" id="name" value="<? echo $rows['value']; ?>">
<input name="name" class="form-control" type="text" id="name" value="<? echo $rows['value']; ?>">
<input name="name" class="form-control" type="text" id="name" value="<? echo $rows['value']; ?>">
<input name="name" class="form-control" type="text" id="name" value="<? echo $rows['value']; ?>">
<input name="name" class="form-control" type="text" id="name" value="<? echo $rows['value']; ?>">

<button type="submit" /> Update </button>
</form>
```

Here is the updated code I added after your suggestion:

```
<?php
require_once("config/database.php");


$con = mysql_connect($config["db_server"],$config["db_user"],$config["db_pass"]);
mysql_select_db($config['db_name'], $con);


// get value of id that sent from address bar
$id=$_GET['form_field_id'];

// Retrieve data from database
$sql="SELECT * FROM options WHERE id='$id'"; 


$result=mysql_query($sql);
$rows=mysql_fetch_array($result);

?>



<form name="form1" method="post" action="updated_values.php">

<?php
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
?>
   <input name="name[]" class="form-control" type="text" id="name" value="<? echo $rows['value']; ?>">
<?php } ?>

<button type="submit" /> Update </button>
</form>
```

Comment: [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in your query, you are passing a variable thta you didn't assign so change first query as follow

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM options WHERE id='$id'"; 
                                   //^here you used a wrong variable
```

You also need to loop throw your records to print all them, so change as follow

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="updated_values.php">

<?php
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
?>
   <input name="name[]" class="form-control" type="text" id="name[]" value="<? echo $rows['value']; ?>">
<?php } ?>

<button type="submit" /> Update </button>
</form>
```

Note that i also changed name of your input and i added `[]` so you will have an array of `name` input.
As side note i'd say your code is highly vulnerable to mysql injection and you should switch either to `mysqli` or `PDO` and use prepared statments to avoid any problems.

Comment: Thanks, still bit confused, how to pull the data using values.php?form_field_id=5 will that load the value into input files?

Comment: You did correctly with `$id=$_GET['form_field_id'];` and then use query i placed in my answer

Comment: please see the updated codes above with the changes with your suggestion, but when I goto url values.php?form_field_id=5  nothing shows, beside the update button

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks right. You just need to change this:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM options WHERE id='$form_field_id'";
```

to this:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM options WHERE form_field_id='$id'";
```

All you had wrong was the variable and the column name, and to show the results you have to properly loop through all the rows you get.